# Using text instead of Select statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down box, this is populated with options that after selecting it shows hidden text by calling the function `toggletDisplay()` and sending the value of the option throug, I want it to be able to do the same but without the drop down box to select, using instead plain text with `onclick()` instead of `onchange()` or something similiar.

Current Code

```
<form id="criteria" name="criteria">

<table width="200px" height="700px" name="criteria_search" align="left" border="1" style="margin-right:70px">
                <tr>
                    <td class="dataLabel" width="100%" align="left"><strong>Add Rule : </strong>
                        <select name="rule" id="rule" onChange="toggletdDisplay(this.form);"> 
                            <optgroup label="Simple Rules">
                                <option value="instructions" selected="selected">&nbsp;</option>
                                <option value="email">Email</option>
                                <option value="assigned">Assigned Racecourse</option>

                            </optgroup>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table align="right"  border="1" width="300px" height="400px" style="float:left;">      
            <tr>


                <td class="dataLabel" name="assigned" id="assigned" style="display: none;">
                    <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                            <td colspan="3"><h4>Assigned to Racecourse</h4></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="margin-left:20px">
                                <b>Assigned To: </b><select name="selected_assigned_location" id="selected_assigned_location"></select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </td>


                <td  width="100px" class="dataLabel" name="email" id="email" style="display: none;" > 
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                            <td colspan="3"><h4>Registered Email</h4></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Do they have a registered Email Account?</b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Yes <input type="radio" name="email_c" value="true_ex" {EMAIL_TEX_CHECKED} checked="checked"> &nbsp; No <input type="radio" name="email_c" value="false" {EMAIL_F_CHECKED}>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
...ect
```

I tried just sending the value through as an onclick

```
            <td>
                <p id="rule" name="rule" value="email" onclick="toggletdDisplay(this.form);">Email</p>
            </td>
```

But I get an error of value rule is undefined. How would I send the value through the same as before but without using a select statement?

Added the toggletDisplay, simply uses the value sent back to change the style of the datalabel from hidden to inline

```
function toggletdDisplay(me) 
{     
    list = Array("instructions","sex", "email", "mobile", "account", "age", "location", "spent", "booked_anything", "internet_booked", "package_type", "package_name", "booked_location", "new_booked_event", "booked_event_range","team", "no_reorder", "newsletter","hear_about","hear_about_bookings","mosaic_group","mosaic_type","assigned","assigned_user","lead_source","target_list","awc","birthday"); 

    // hide any previously selected elements
    for(x=0; x<list.length; x++) 
    {
        deselect = getElementsByName_iefix("TD", list[x]);
        for (j=0; j<deselect.length; j++) 
        {
            deselect[j].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    // display currently selected criteria
    selected = getElementsByName_iefix("TD", me.rule.value);
    selected[0].style.display = "inline";
}
```

Comment: Any data that you want submitted needs to be in some sort of form field elements.  `<p>` is not one of those elements.  Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/The_native_form_widgets) for your options.  Perhaps you want to populate a [hidden input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/The_native_form_widgets#Hidden_content) on click.

Comment: There is an opening form tag right at the beginning. The closing form tag is missing but I assume that it should encompass the whole table structure.

Comment: @PatrickQ This is not about submitting the data, that works fine, this is about calling the toggletdDisplay() function by sending a value the same way as drop down box, but as a simple clickable text field, or something similar to display the hidden attributes

Comment: @cars10m Yes, everything closes fine and this system works, its the changes I don't know how to make thats the problem, not the current code

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a number of issues with your code. One of them is the undefined function `toggletdDisplay()` that is called whenever you change the selection in your select field.

But, basically, if you want to send a value of an input field or a select box within a form to a php script on your server you will need to define an `action` attribute in your `<form>` tag and make sure that the form is submitted. This can be achieved in your case by changing the `onchange` attribute in your select box (simplified code, without the table architecture):

Whenever you change the selection in your select box the form will be submitted and the value of that select box will be sent to `target.php`. The address line in your browser will show something like

```
...<your URL>/target.php?rule=email
```

It is also not clear to me why you use `colspan` attributes in some of your `<td>`-elements, as there is only one column to display in that table.

My advice is to be economical with "cut and paste" and only use code that you fully understand. Build your page slowly, step by step. That way you will be able to understand what needs to be fixed if something goes wrong.

**Edit**

With your `toggletdDisplay()` script we have something to work on. The first thing that springs to my mind is that you are not using jquery functions where they might be helpful. And secondly, you don't do anything to display the form values in the console window or send them to a php script.

It is also important to note that `name` attributes can only be assigned to `<input>` or `<select>` elements and *not* to `<td>` elements. In my following script I used the `id` attribute instead.

```js
var tds,tdis;
$(function(){
 var list = ["instructions","sex", "email", "mobile", "account", "age", "location", "spent", "booked_anything", "internet_booked", "package_type", "package_name", "booked_location", "new_booked_event", "booked_event_range","team", "no_reorder", "newsletter","hear_about","hear_about_bookings","mosaic_group","mosaic_type","assigned","assigned_user","lead_source","target_list","awc","birthday"]; 
 // consider only TDs with IDs from list array:
 tds= $('td').filter(function(i,el){return $.inArray(el.id,list)>-1;});
 // trigger the display of results only for select and input elements within tds:
 tdis=$('select,input', tds).on('change',listResults);
 // assign the toggletdDispla function to the rule selector:
 $('.action').on('change',toggletdDisplay);
});

function toggletdDisplay(){ tds.hide().filter('#'+this.value).show()}
function listResults(){
  $('#show').html('<p>Values to be sent:</p>'+tdis.serialize().replace(/&/g,'<br/>'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="target.php">
<table name="criteria_search" align="left" border="1" style="margin-right:70px">
<tr><td class="dataLabel"><strong>Add Rule : </strong>
  <select name="rule" id="rule" class="action"> 
   <optgroup label="Simple Rules">
    <option value="instructions" selected="selected">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="email">Email</option>
    <option value="assigned">Assigned Racecourse</option>
   </optgroup>
  </select>
</td><td class="dataLabel" id="email" style="display:none">
  <b>email:</b>
  <br/><label><input type="radio" name="email_c" value="true_ex"> yes</label>
  <br/><label><input type="radio" name="email_c" value="false"> no</label>
  <br/><label><input type="radio" name="email_c" value="soon"> not yet</label>
 </td>
<td class="dataLabel" id="assigned" style="display:none">
  Racecourse<br/>
  <b>Assigned To: </b>
  <select name="selected_assigned_location">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="a">racecourse A</option>
   <option value="b">racecourse B</option>
   <option value="c">racecourse C</option>
  </select>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form><br style="clear:both" />
<div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: I think my question was a bit ambiguous, currently when I select something from the dropdown it shows more fields, input boxes, labels ect, it doesn't send anything ot the form. All I need is to have something I can click and it shows the specific value, e.g. "email" or "assigned" fields next to it, this is done by calling the toggletdDisplay() and sending through the me.rule.value = "value". As for my colspans, yes a lot of the fields are repeated and could easily be achieved through copy and paste, the few I used are out of 30 options and are the ones that the colspan isn't really required.

Comment: Have included my toggletDisplay() in the question